# Like Button disappears on page refresh

Tags: html, facebook-like

Here is what I have in my code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" 
  data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-href="${appurl}">
</div>
```

The value of the appurl is of the form: `http://www.mysite.com/action/detail/123`

When I click on the like button, everything works fine and I can see the update on my facebook page.

Now, When I refresh the page the like button disappears.

However, when I give the appurl as `"http://www.mysite.com"` everything works including on page refresh (I can see the like button).

Please help what I am missing here?.

Comment: Yes we are using jquery. But i have tried the same urls with standalone html files which is not having any jquery files included. Still that particular url is failing to load the like button. Basically  <div id="LikePluginPagelet"> div not having any content in the facebook response. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are your site's pages protected with an .htaccess password? If so, that could be the issue. I ran into this problem myself, and after going down the wrong path for a bit, I went back to my initial suspicion - htaccess password.

I didn't really look into the code, but I assume the button is set to have FB scrape the page after a user clicks like. With the password blocking things, FB can't scrape the page. Rather than displaying the button as if it hadn't been clicked, it just displays nothing - which is where my, and I assume your, confusion came in.

After changing htaccess, you'll have to wait 24 hours for the page(s) to be scraped by FB when they're loaded. However, you can use the FB debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to manually scrape individual pages.

Comment: Hi Kris, Thanks much for the response. I have verified regarding the htaccess protection. we have not done anythying that uses htaccess for the page access restriction. I have noticed, some of the url which actualy renders the like button once the page is liked and refreshed. But i have noticed difference in the response coming from facebook for the working and non working url's of our application.Non Working version has the empty <div id="LikePluginPagelet"></div>  from the response. Please show some light on this.